# Will using 2 soundpools cause me any kind of memory leak?

Tags: android, soundpool

I would like to use two soundpools in my activity. One that I will unload and release sometimes and load it with different sounds, then I unload/release again and use it again with other sounds, and another one that will always contain the same sounds and will never be unloaded. I didnt find any words about this in the documentation, so will it cause me any kind of problem? 
And if I use the constant sounds with MediaPlayer instead of SoundPool? Will it cause any memory leak or problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be no memory leaks or sound playback issues, if you correctly handle your `SoundPool` and `MediaPlayer` objects in terms of your `Activity` lifecycle (see below).

First of all, you shouldn't make "too many" `SoundPool` and `MediaPlayer` objects. This depends on the actual state of your device, but I'm sure you'll be OK with 2 `SoundPool` objects and e.g. 4 `MediaPlayer` objects, simultaneously.

Explanation: each `SoundPool` reserves one native `AudioTrack`, and each `MediaPlayer` also reserves one native `AudioTrack`. Therefore, with 2 `SoundPool` and 4 `MediaPlayer` objects, you will have 6 underlying `AudioTrack` objects in use. This is usually fine, as the system usually has many more free `AudioTrack` objects. (For more detailed information, see [this topic](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-platform/tyITQ09vV3s/discussion).)

Regarding your concrete question: yes, it's also OK to use a permanent `SoundPool` and another `SoundPool` which you recreate/release sometimes, as long as you take into account the following point:

- In the `onPause()` or `onStop()` event handler of your activity, you should **release all** `SoundPool` and `MediaPlayer` objects, because they use native resources. Then in your `onResume()` or `onStart()`, you can recreate them again. So your statement *"... will never be unloaded"* isn't correct in this sense, because you need to handle the state of `SoundPool` and `MediaPlayer` objects across your `Activity` lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I actually asked this, because when I wanted to play 20-25 media player sounds after each other, the last 8-9 never played however the first 15 or 16 ones played well. I changed to SoundPool and now I can handle it, but I would be VERY curious for the hard limit for MediaPlayer objects.

Comment: The theoretical hard limit of Android is 32 native AudioTracks per device (which means that the total number of the SoundPool, MediaPlayer and other AudioTrack-based objects cannot exceed 32). As Glenn Kasten pointed out in the article I linked to, the actual number of available tracks is certainly smaller. This is because the system and other applications may also use them. So your question about hard limit cannot be answered with an exact value, because it may depend on the device (i.e. even on manufacturer), on your device state (what is running on it), and so on.